# Setup ubuntu server on Raspberry Pi 4 without keyboard

Tags: server, ssh, keyboard

I have a display and a USB mouse but don't have a keyboard. I realize that ubuntu asks me to enter new password for the initial user setup. Is there any alternate way to install ubuntu server without keyboard on a Raspberry pi 4? Is it possible to ssh into ubuntu server without initial setup?

Comment: Ubuntu server comes without a graphical user interface. I need to login first to even get to the desktop.

Comment: you need at least one computer that has a keyboard attached to it and the ability to modify the raspberry sdcard. You need to place a file inside the boot folder of the sdcard. The empty file needs to be named SSH. Now replug it into your raspberry pi. After booting you should now be able to ssh into your pi.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I do have my laptop, but that method works with Raspian OS and not on anything else.

Comment: I did try this from this website and still no luck. https://www.berthon.eu/2017/installing-ubuntu-server-on-raspberry-pi-headless/

Comment: the default os for raspberry is raspbian. its maintained from the raspberry producers. i suggest you stick to that os. if you do not want a gui just pick the raspbian lite version. i do the same. ubuntu server did not run stable the last time i used it on my pi2 - https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ and follow the instructions for a headless install **3. Enable SSH on a headless Raspberry Pi** https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md#3-enable-ssh-on-a-headless-raspberry-pi-add-file-to-sd-card-on-another-machine

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The "ssh" file seems to work for me. I just installed the RPi 4 with ubuntu-server 19.10.1. Here are the full instructions for anbody who finds it:

After you have installed ubuntu-server to your SD-card, mount the first partition (usually /dev/mmcblk0p1) on the machine that you installed the SD-card with.

Next, create a file called "ssh" on the filesystem root (it does not have to have any content, as long as the file is there when the pi boots the first time, it will enable ssh).

You then should find the ip address of your pi using either the web-ui on your modem, or by running the following comand from a linux box with nmap installed:
nmap -p 22 / (e.g.: nmap -p 22 192.168.1.1/24)

Now you can ssh into the machine with the username "ubuntu" and password "ubuntu". It will then ask you to change the password and disconnect you. That's it, you should have a new password.

Comment: I verified this works on Ubuntu Server 64-bit 18.04 LTS on Raspberry Pi 4. Thanks!

Comment: Note: You must add the SSH file *before* first boot. Tested on Ubuntu Server 64-bit 18.04 LTS on Raspberry Pi 4. Tried to add the SSH file after unsuccessful first boot but had to reflash the card image.

Comment: @Wirewrap thanks for the extra information (that I did not even know about myself!

Comment: @wirewrap is there any way to reverse the first boot flag? Or is the only way to reflash the sd card?

Comment: @ws6079 I don’t know of any.

Comment: Is there a good way to automatically set up public key authentication? I'd like to be able to bake my public key into the image so I can pop the same image into each Pi with minimal customization after boot.

Answer (score 2):

I recently purchased several RPi4's and installing Ubuntu 20.04 server on them headless most of @pasulio's advice was spot on. One thing that I've noticed with all the Raspberry Pi's is that I needed to do the steps like so from my Macbook:

- `touch /Volumes/system-boot/ssh`
- unmount SD
- boot RPi and `ssh ubuntu@<ip>`
- Set a new password
- Reboot the RPi

When SSH'ing into the RPi initially the screen will appear like so:

```
$ ssh ubuntu@192.168.7.5
Last login: Thu Sep 10 01:54:19 2020 from 192.168.13.10
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for ubuntu.
Current password:
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: password updated successfully
Shared connection to 192.168.7.5 closed.
```

**NOTE:** Repeated attempts to SSH would only result in continual re-prompts to change the password, until a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed ubuntu server 22 for raspberry on my raspberrypi 4 and i do nothing, just connected with "ubuntu@x.x.x.x" with password "ubuntu" and it work. No need to create "ssh" empty file.